# how to mount storage and data partitions in recovery mode in adb shell?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb-debugging

iam a newbie.but i have learnt adb commands.
i need to enable **usb debugging** through adb shell commands.
i am confused with terminologies itself so please answer simply.

**steps i want to perform:**
1.boot into recovery mode
2.run adb shell
3.mount system & data partitions
4.*some adb commands...*

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a custom recovery:
**CWM (Clockworkmod-based)**:
1. Use volume buttons to navigate and power button to select
2. Find "**Mounts and storage**" menu
3. Select "Mount /system" and "Mount /data"

**TWRP (TeamWin's)**:
1. Tap "Mount" in main menu
2. Tap "**data**" and "**system**"

**Manual way** (using `adb` command):
Run `adb shell` and run these in the given sub-shell:

```
mount -o rw /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system
mount -o rw /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/data /data
```

In case `/dev/block/bootdevice` doesn't exist, run:

```
fdisk -l /dev/block/mmcblk0
# If it shows a lot of entries, find the partition number of system and data manually then
mount -o rw /dev/block/mmcblk0pX /system
mount -o rw /dev/block/mmcblk0pY /data
# X and Y are the numbers you found from fdisk's output
```

Comment: i am getting this error `error: device '(null)' not found`i have installed google usb drivers my phone's drivers and everything is fine.although i haven't turned on usb debugging.because my touch is broken.by the way my struggle is to turn on usb debugging and use phone  by mirroring to my pc

Answer (score 0):

mount /sys/block/mmcblk0xxx /data
You will need to replace "xxx" by proper partition value, it depends on your device.

Same applies for system.